# Error: 'else' without a previous "if' even though there is not a semicolon

Tags: c++, if-statement, comma-operator

I made a very simple program but even though there is not a semicolon, I still get this error. Please ignore the weird intention of this program, it's for comedy purposes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the blessing service" << endl;
    cout << "please enter your name and god will" << endl;
    cout << "decide if you are cursed or blessed" << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
    cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
        cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
        cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
        cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your statement “blocks” are missing braces.

Comment: `if ( ... ) { ... } else { ... }` then you should be golden

Comment: C++ is not python. You need to surround everything between `if()` and `else` in `{}` unless it's a single statement (and even in that case I recommend adding the `{}`).

Comment: It is tangential, but I would also question the validity of `if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)`.

Comment: Remember that white space like indentation does not have any functional impact on the code, beyond separating tokens. Only the expression immediately following the `if` is considered as part of the conditional branch, which is why `{}` are used when you want to do more than one thing in that branch.

Comment: `cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;` is going to expect the user to provide a single number, store is in `john`. The comma operator doesn't do what you expect, it just evaluates each operand and results in the last operand. A trial-and-error approach is not feasible for learning C++. Consider getting a reputable book.

Comment: As mentioned by n0rd `if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)` probably doesn't do what you expect it to do: this evaluates `john`, `jeff`, `philip` and `joe` and yields `dave` resulting in the if having the same effect as `if(dave != 0)` in this scenario. Turn on compiler warnings to detect this accidentally occuring; e.g. gcc would warn you about the dropped values, if you compile with the `-Wall` flag

Comment: Handy reading: [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) Gory details: [Built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters  in this expression statement

```
cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
```

there is used the comma operator. It is equivalent to

```
( cin >> john ), ( jeff ), ( philip ), ( joe ), ( dave );
```

So all the operands after the first operand

```
( jeff ), ( philip ), ( joe ), ( dave )
```

do not produce any effect.

It seems you mean

```
cin >> john >> jeff >> philip >> joe >> dave;
```

Again in the condition of this if statement

```
if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
```

there is used an expression with the same comma operator. The value of the expression is the value of last operand `dave` contextually converted to the type bool.

It is unclear what you are trying to check in this if statement.

Nevertheless the following pair of statements should be enclosed in a compound statement like

```
if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
{
    cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
    cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
    cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
}
```

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Hello and welcome to the blessing service" << endl;
    cout << "please enter your name and god will" << endl;
    cout << "decide if you are cursed or blessed" << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________" << endl;

    cin >> name;

    if (name == "john" || name == "jeff" || name == "philip" || name == "joe" || name == "dave")
    {
        cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
        cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
        cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
    }

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The condition in the if statement can be changed as you like.

Answer (score 1):

this code

```
if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
    cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
    cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
else
    cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
    cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
system ("pause");
```

is actually

```
if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
    cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
else
    cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
system ("pause");
```

indentation has no meaning for c++, you need

```
if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave){
    cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
    cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
    cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
}
system ("pause");
```

it also highly unlikel that the cin and if do what you want. I suspect you are trying to test if somebody's name is John or Jeff etc

in that case you need

```
    string name;
    cin >> name;
```

then

```
    if(name=="Jeff"||name = "John||name ==......)
```

Comment: I'd also point out that `if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)` and `cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;` are definitely not going to do what they intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't use `{}` around the body of your `if` code the compiler reads your code as if it looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the blessing service" << endl;
    cout << "please enter your name and god will" << endl;
    cout << "decide if you are cursed or blessed" << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
    cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
    {
        cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
    }
        cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
    }
        cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You should do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    cout << "Hello and welcome to the blessing service" << endl;
    cout << "please enter your name and god will" << endl;
    cout << "decide if you are cursed or blessed" << endl;
    cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
    cin >> john, jeff, philip, joe, dave;
    if (john, jeff, philip, joe, dave)
    {
        cout << "you have been cursed, you will have bad luck" << endl;
        cout << "for the rest of your life!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "you have been blessed, enjoy your life" << endl;
        cout << "and keep praying to God" << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```